# DecodeError: Error parsing message with type 'tensorflow.GraphDef'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to load weights from an epoch checkpoint while training a Tensorflow Recommenders Deep Retrieval model and then save the model. When trying to save the model, it gives the following error:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:581] String field 'tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.Dim.name' contains invalid UTF-8 data when parsing a protocol buffer. Use the 'bytes' type if you intend to send raw bytes.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DecodeError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_8016/3029885622.py in <module>
      1 brute_model.save(destination_path)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _as_graph_def(self, from_version, add_shapes)
   3525           data = pywrap_tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(buf)
   3526       graph = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
-> 3527       graph.ParseFromString(compat.as_bytes(data))
   3528       # Strip the experimental library field iff it's empty.
   3529       if not graph.library.function:

DecodeError: Error parsing message with type 'tensorflow.GraphDef'
```

`brute_model` is the index generated by:

```
tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.BruteForce(query_model).index_from_dataset(tf.data.Dataset.zip((unique_labels.batch(50), unique_labels.batch(50).map(candidate_model))))
```